# Rails Coffeescript not executing properly at page load

Tags: ruby-on-rails, coffeescript, turbolinks

I have a nav-bar menu that is displayed in traditional horizontal nav bar format.  With small screen sizes I would like to use coffeescript to remove the nav element with the links and append it to a dropdown menu activated by clicking on a hamburger link.

The trouble Im having is that the above action isnt always executing only about 30% of the time.  This makes me wonder if its Turbolinks or my profound noobishness with coffeescript?  The code is below. Am I doing this right?

(.small) is my CSS class hidden at greater than 768 with a media query

```
ready = ->  

    $( window ).resize(menuAdjust)


    $('.hamburger').click ->
        $('#hidden').toggle(  )


menuAdjust = ->
 if ($(".small").css("display") == "block")
     $('#menu').appendTo('#hidden');
 else
     $('#menu').appendTo('#main')

$(document).ready(ready)
$(document).ready(menuAdjust)
$(document).on('page:load', ready)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your CoffeeScript code will only trigger `menuAdjust` when a user resizes the browser window because you have only registered `menuAdjust` with the `ready()` callback and not the 'page:load' event as well. E.g menuAdjust will only be triggered on a full page refresh and not a Turbolinks page load. Register `menuAdjust` to also execute on the Turbolinks page load event:

```
$(document).on('page:load', menuAdjust)
```

You can also temporarily [disable Turbolinks](http://blog.steveklabnik.com/posts/2013-06-25-removing-turbolinks-from-rails-4) to be certain this is the cause of the issue.